# Getting error by Django insert queries caused by duplicates

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add some data into table made in Django.

Here is my code:

```
class Prefixe(models.Model):
    remote_as = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    prefix_list = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)


def insert():
    p = Prefixe(remote_as='Apress', prefix_list='Berkeley')
    p.save()
```

I'm creating records using ORM and it fails with "duplicates" exception (see `unique` option in prefix_list definition).

But there is a way I can avoid this exception if I make insert as raw SQL with specific PG option:

```
INSERT INTO "peer_table" ("remote_as","prefix_list")
VALUES('{}','{}')
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

Can I avoid this exception caused by duplicates when working via ORM?

Comment: If you get an error, I assume the duplicates will not be accepted in Python solution either, correct? You are simply lacking the error handling, which depends on the kind of error, which you are not providing details about. One possibly way, exception handling, would be via try/except.

Comment: in Python it works! because i use postgres(ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING)

Comment: So what means the final line of your question?

Comment: Make use of [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could benefit from the use of the method [`.get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
def insert(remote_as, prefix_list):
    p, was_created = Prefixe.objects.get_or_create(
        remote_as=remote_as, prefix_list=prefix_list)

    if was_create:
        print('a new instance was created.')
    else:
        print('the instance already exists.')
```